# How to prove that the Douady-Hubbard conformal map from the exterior of Mandelbrot Set to exterior of unit disc is actually holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis, dynamical-systems, connectedness, conformal-geometry, complex-dynamics

I was reading the Orsay Notes on Exploring the Mandelbrot Set. ([https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hubbard/OrsayEnglish.pdf](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehubbard/OrsayEnglish.pdf))
On Page 64, it is proven that the Mandelbrot Set is connected.
I understood the rest of the proof but I can't understand the part where they prove that $\Phi:\mathbb{C}\backslash M\mapsto \mathbb{C}\backslash \mathbb{D}$, given by $\Phi(c)=\phi_c(c)$ is holomorphic. It is just stated that $(z,c)\to \phi_c(z)$ is holomorphic in two variables ($z\in\mathbb{C}:G_c(z)>G_c(0))$. I don't understand how is this proved and how does this even imply the holmorphicity of $\Phi(c)=\phi_c(c)$.

(The notations are as used in the book).

Answer (score 1):

To prove holomorphicity in two variables, you just need to prove continuity and then holomorphicity with respect to each variable separately. Just go through the construction of $\phi$ and check it (it is constructed as a locally uniform limit of holomorphic functions).

For the second question how this implies holomorphicity of $\Phi$, this is just the fact that $\Phi$ is the composition of the two holomorphic maps $c \mapsto (c,c)$ and $(z,c) \mapsto \phi_c(z)$.